# Py: Limit when fetching from database and executing script from console

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, console, pymysql

This subject can be already covered. If so, apologizes for that. I have a problem when fetching rows from database (with "for" and "while" loops) and executing the script from console.

I need to fetch a huge amount of rows from database and I'm building a script so that i can insert the user ID's and i'll get the account ID's of the clients and the statuses.
I have realized that when I run the script from Eclipse, full output is fetched from DB. When I run the script from console, there is a limit of rows. So, i'd like to know if i have a "while row is not None" loop... why my row becomes None if there are more rows in database??

Also: I need to solve this issue. No matter how. I'd prefer to not load the full list to a local file (if possible). But, if there is no other way... okay, please help!! This is my example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8

import configparser
import pymysql
from prettytable import PrettyTable

conn = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=password, db=database)

print()
userid = input('Insert User ID(s) > ') # userid is a list of 2000 users in comma-separated format
userids = userid.replace(" ", "").replace("'", "").replace(",", "','")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(""" SELECT user_ID, account_ID, status FROM Account WHERE user_ID IN ('%s'); """ % userids)
rows = cur.fetchall()

table = PrettyTable(["user_ID", "account_ID", "status"])
table.padding_width = 1

for line in rows:
    user_ID = str(line[0])
    account_ID = str(line[1])
    status = str(line[2])
    table.add_row([user_ID, account_ID, status])

print()
print(table)
conn.close()
print()
print()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying too much your code you could try using [`from_db_cursor()`](https://github.com/lmaurits/prettytable/blob/master/prettytable.py#L1593) provided by the `prettytable` module like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pymysql
from prettytable import from_db_cursor

conn = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=password, db=database)

userid = input('Insert User ID(s) > ') # userid is a list of 2000 users in comma-separated format
userids = userid.replace(" ", "").replace("'", "").replace(",", "','")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(""" SELECT user_ID, account_ID, status FROM Account WHERE user_ID IN ('%s'); """ % userids)

table = from_db_cursor(cur, padding_width=1)

print(table)
conn.close()
```

But looking at the source code of `prettytable` my guess is that it won't change the situation much since it does more or less what you were doing explicitly in your code.

---

What would probably work better is to add rows one at a time to `table` instead of fetching all rows and looping through them to add them. Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pymysql
from prettytable import PrettyTable

conn = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=password, db=database)

userid = input('Insert User ID(s) > ') # userid is a list of 2000 users in comma-separated format
userids = userid.replace(" ", "").replace("'", "").replace(",", "','")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(""" SELECT user_ID, account_ID, status FROM Account WHERE user_ID IN ('%s'); """ % userids)
row = cur.fetchone()

table = PrettyTable(["user_ID", "account_ID", "status"], padding_width=1)

while row is not None:
    table.add_row(row)
    row = cur.fetchone()

print(table)
conn.close()
```

You don't need to transform the row elements to string values since `Prettytable` does that internally.

---

But it is possible to take advantage of different features to simplify your code and to make it more pythonic:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import pymysql
from prettytable import PrettyTable

userid = input('Insert User ID(s) > ') # userid is a list of 2000 users in comma-separated format
userids = re.sub("[ ']", "", userid).replace(",", "','")

table = PrettyTable(["user_ID", "account_ID", "status"], padding_width=1)

with pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=password, db=database) as cur:
    cur.execute("""SELECT user_ID, account_ID, status FROM Account WHERE user_ID IN ('%s'); """ % userids)

    map(table.add_row, cur)

print(table)
```

In this version:

- I have used the [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to do some of the substitutions (some may say that's a tad overkill but it could be useful to you in the future)
- A `Pymysql` connection [implements](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/connections.py#L830) the [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) that provides you directly with a cursor.
- Since a `Pymysql` cursor can [provide](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/cursors.py#L357) an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) we can use it with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to go through all the rows even if we don't care for the result.